# Can the Atlas search filter in MongoDB cloud be used to query between dates?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas-search

All the examples I read online seem to refer to using the compass or the command line, not MongoDB cloud. I try emulate the same query code in the search filter but not having any luck.

[Search function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7yn8.jpg)

For example with the sample collections..

```
_id:ObjectId("5bd761dcae323e45a93ccff1")
saleDate:2014-08-18T04:37:26.849+00:00
storeLocation:"Denver"
couponUsed:false
purchaseMethod:"In store"


_id:ObjectId("5bd761dcae323e45a93ccff7")
saleDate:2017-12-08T21:40:34.527+00:00
storeLocation:"Denver"
couponUsed:false
purchaseMethod:"Phone"


_id:ObjectId("5bd761dcae323e45a93ccfef")
saleDate:2014-03-31T16:02:06.624+00:00
storeLocation:"Austin"
couponUsed:false
purchaseMethod:"Online"
```

How could I filter saleDate to show objects from 2014?

Answer (score 1):

Botti you want to use the [range operator](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/range) in `$search` pipeline:

```
{
    "$search": {
       "index": "<index Name>",
       "range": {
          "path": "saleDate",
          "gte":"2014-03-31T16:02:06.624+00:00",
          "lte": "2017-12-08T21:40:34.527+00:00"
       }
    }
}
```